# Value Error : "DoctorPerHospital.doc_id" must be a "DoctorUserProfile" instance

Tags: api, foreign-keys, django-rest-framework

I Have a DoctorUserProfile extended by Django User model.
I have another model, DoctorPerHospital, which extends DoctorUserProfile to store data related to particular doctor.

I have used DRF to create API's and i created an API which adds data to DoctorPerHospital model and link the DoctorUserProfile to for the current user to it.
I am facing the error saying  should instance of 
models.py

```
class DoctorUserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    spec = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DOCTOR_TYPE, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    education = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=DOCTOR_EDU, default=PHY, db_index=True)
    profile_image = VersatileImageField('doctor_images', upload_to="doctor_images/", null=True, blank=True)
    experience = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    speciality = models.ForeignKey(Specialities, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    app_label = 'pwave'

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % (self.name)



class DoctorPerHospital(models.Model):
    doc_id = models.ForeignKey(DoctorUserProfile, null=True, blank=True)
    hospital = models.ForeignKey(HospitalUserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    appointment_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    discounted_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)

class Meta:
    app_label = 'pwave'

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' %(self.doc_id)
```

Serializers.py

```
class DoctorInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DoctorUserProfile
        fields = ('id','user','name','age','gender','spec','education',
            'profile_image','experience','speciality')
        read_only_fields = ('user',)

class DoctorPerHospitalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DoctorPerHospital
        fields = ('id','doc_id','hospital','appointment_cost','discount','discounted_cost')
        read_only_fields = ('doc_id',)
```

views.py

```
class DoctorPerHospitalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DoctorPerHospital.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DoctorPerHospitalSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            profile = serializer.save()
            current_user = DoctorUserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            print(current_user.id)
            profile.doc_id = current_user.id
            profile.save()
            return Response(serializer.validated_data)
        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad request',
            'message': 'Account could not be created with provided data'
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The error statement is as follows :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your current models and serializer.

First the `doc_id` is misnamed in the `DoctorPerHospital` model. It should be `doc` as Django ORM will use a model instance. Note that if it's named `doc` then you'll have an extra field that will represent the key stored in the database which will be `doc_id` - i.e. `<foreign key field name>_id`

Next you should change the user `ForeignKey` of the `DoctorUserProfile`  model to a `OneToOneField` which will ensure there's a one to one relation between your `DoctorUserProfile` and your `User`

Last is about the serializer's create. `doc` is a `DoctorUserProfile` instance while `request.user` is a `User` instance. You should use the reversed `DoctorUserProfile`'s user to get the profile from the `User` instance.

Comment: I solved the error, i was calling current_user.id instaed of current_user in my vies.py.
BUt Thanks for the suggestions, importantly the doc_id one.